# Is there a way to only click when the opacity of an image is at 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image that is clickable and it starts with an `opacity` of `0` and animates to `1` when it's being hovered on. Is there a way to only make it clickable when the animation is done and the `opacity` is at `1`?

Comment: Sure, what have you tried?

Comment: You could use a flag which gets set on completion of the animation, or you could check the `opacity` value within the click handler and stop execution if it's `< 1`.

Comment: A third alternative is to only attach the click handler when the animation is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i believe you're looking for something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).fadeTo( 3000 , 1 );
    });
    $('img').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).css('opacity') == 1) {
            alert('you can click it now');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
img {
    opacity: 0;    
}
div{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/2f/cc/b2/2fccb29f96bf7f0b0ea94d42832a4c4f.jpg"/>
</div>
```

the function `.on('click')` is preventing any default action of clicking the image initially using the `e.preventDefault()` line of code. it then checks if the opacity of the image is `1` and then you can place your code there to do whatever you want it to do on click when opacity is `1`.

hope this helps!